# Geometric distribution over a lifetime resulting from a Poisson distribution with exponential rate

Tags: probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution, geometric-distribution

Let's consider that some particles get created at rate $\beta$ following a Poisson distribution over a period $\tau$ i.e. if X is the number of created particles, then $X \sim Poisson(\beta)$.

A particle gets transformed from state A to state B at rate $\alpha$. i.e. transforming $\sim Exp(\alpha)$ and that the number of transformed particles follows a poisson process.

We are only looking at these particles during this lifetime $\tau$.

I want to determine **the number of particles that are still in a state A at time $\tau$**.

What I only got to determine is that $\beta \, \tau$ particles are created and the probability of a particle reaching age $\tau$ without transforming is $1 - e^{- \alpha \tau}$ but the probability of reaching age $\tau$ is only valid if the particle got created at time 0, right ?

I know that if $X \sim Poisson(Y)$ and $Y \sim Exp(\alpha)$, then, $X \sim Geom(\frac{1}{1+\alpha})$. How can I use this in this situation ?

How can I interpret the Geometric distribution ? What are the failures/successes ?

Also I imagine it's not possible to have more transformed particles than created ones, how do we account for that ?

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Hi: Assuming what you say is true about the distribution being geometric ( I believe you. I just never knew that )  the geometric represents an until type of event. So, how many failures occur before a success. So, if you had a fair coin, the number of tails until you got a head is geometric with  $p = \frac{1}{2}$,  So, you can take an expected value which would be the expected number of failures before you got a head. I'm not familiar with the  framework you described but the analog would be the expected number of times the particle stayed in its same state  before it  transitioned.

Comment: Hi, thank you ! So do you mean the expected number of times one (1) particle stays in state A before it transforms ? I understand the interpretation of the coin analogy but I fail to understand what's the equivalent of 'flipping a coin here', is it just waiting until it transforms ?

Also do you have an idea how this relates to the total number of particules that transformed by time $\tau$ ?

Comment: Are you saying the *time* it takes for a particle to move from state has an $\exp(\alpha)$ distribution?

Comment: I'm rather saying that a particle goes from state A to state B at rate $\alpha$. 
So P[particle still at state A at time t] = $e^{-\alpha t}$

Conversely, P[particle transformed before time t ] = 1 - $e^{-\alpha t}$
(at least, this is how I understood it)

Now the probability that a particle is still at state A at time t depends on the time of its creation. Particles are created independently and with the same probability all along so the distribution of their ages is Unif(0, $\tau$)

Comment: So, for example, if $\tau=10$, and if some particle is born at time $2$, then the probability that this particle is still in state $A$ at time $\tau$ is $e^{-8\alpha}$?

Comment: Yes, I believe so, since it needs to live for 8 units of time to get to time $\tau = 10$

Comment: Let $E_i$ denote the event that the $i^{\text{th}}$ particle born is alive and exists in state $A$ at time $\tau$. The *total* number of particles that exist in state $A$ at time $\tau$ is $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}1_{E_i}$. If $T_i\sim \text{Erlang}\left(i,\frac{\beta}{\tau}\right)$ is the time the $i^{\text{th}}$ particle was born, then $$\mathbb{P}(E_i)=\int_0^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(E_i|T_i=t)f_{T_i}(t)\mathrm{d}t=\int_0^{\tau}e^{-\alpha(\tau -t)}f_{T_i}(t)\mathrm{d}t$$

Comment: Note $\mathbb{P}(E_i)$ depends on $i$ so our "success" probability isn't the same on each trial. This suggests the distribution of $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}1_{E_i}$ isn't geometric.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :) 
I just have a remark, if we assume that particles are created independently and with the same probability, wouldn't it be that $T_i \sim \text{Unif}(0, \tau)$, then 

$$\mathbb{P}(E_i) = \int_{0}^{\tau} \frac{1}{\tau} e^{-\alpha (\tau - t)} \, dt = \frac {1 - e^{- \alpha \tau}}{\alpha \, \tau}$$

Comment: Interatrial times in your birthing Poisson process are $\exp(\beta/\tau)$ which means your birthing times have an Erlang distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\Big\{[t_{i-1},t_i),s_i\Big\}_{i=1}^n$ be a uniform tagged partition of $[0,\tau)$.

If $X_i$ is the number of individuals born in $[t_{i-1},t_i)$ *that remain in state $A$ at time $\tau$,* then $X_i$ is approximately $\text{Poisson}\left(\frac{\beta(t_i-t_{i-1})}{\tau}e^{-\alpha(\tau-s_i)}\right)$ when $n$ is large.

If we put $X=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ then $X$ is the *total* number of individuals born in $[0,\tau)$ that remain in state $A$ at time $\tau$ which, from independence, is approximately $\text{Poisson}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\beta(t_i-t_{i-1})}{\tau}e^{-\alpha(\tau-s_i)}\right)$.

Taking $n$ to infinity tells us the distribution you seek is $\text{Poisson}\left(\int_0^\tau \frac{\beta}{\tau}e^{-\alpha(\tau-x)}\mathrm{d}x\right)$

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough answer ! :) By any chance did you forget to include $\alpha$ or is intentional ? As I've been trying it I find that it is Poisson$(\int_{0}^{\tau} \frac{\beta}{\tau} e^{- \alpha (\tau - x)} \, dx)$

Comment: Yes, you are correct! I dropped the $\alpha$. Fixing it now.

Comment: @rubyOnSails: It looks like Matthew H derived an expression without using the geometric distribution ( I'll try to understand it when I have more time ) so let's not go there. I wasn't sure to be honest, how to apply the geometric to your problem because the geometric is a distribution for an event ( success or failure ) rather than the number of particles. In your case, I think it would have applied to one particle, assuming it was applicable, but like I said, I'm not absolutely sure that it was applicable. Apologies for noise and thanks to Matthew H.

Comment: I have a small question about the Poisson distribution you provided. Does this mean that the expected number of produced particule during the time $[\tau -a, \tau)$ is $a \, \int_{0}{\tau}\frac{\beta}{\tau}e^{-\alpha(\tau-x)}\, dx$ ?

Comment: @markleeds Thank you ! I also couldn't think of a plausible interpretation of the success/failure in this case, so I'm kind of stuck on that front

Comment: @MatthewH. or in other words, is the distribution of particles that are created during $[t, \tau)$ that are still in state A at time $\tau$ is the same as the one for $[0, \tau)$ and the interval length is only reflected in the expectation (when the rate of the Poisson distribution is multiplied by the corresponding time interval)

Comment: @rubyonSails: I looked at this more closely and ( without understanding the Erlang ), one can think of it this way. The rate that new particles are getting created is Poisson $(\frac{\beta \triangle t_{i}}{\tau})$ and the rate that they are leaving is exponential$(\alpha (x - s_{i})$. Since birthing process and the leaving process are independent, they can be multiplied. This is where Matthew gets his statement that the number of particles remaining at time $\tau$ is approximately Poisson distributed with such rate. Then, he lets $n$ go to infinity so that the intervals get tinier and tinier.

Comment: Hi @markleeds thank you for your time ans answer ! I agree however how can I multiply a Poisson process with an Exponential one ? What would be the resulting distribution and its rate ?

Comment: Hi rubyOnSails: I'm not sure what the resulting distribution is ( if there is a closed form distribution, it would need to be normalized ) but, if you have two densities, say f(x) and g(y), and the two  are independent of each other, then multiplying them to get f(x) * g(y) is a legal operation. So, it doesn't really matter what the distribution is as long as you get a closed form that you can integrate.  Note that  the $\sum (\beta (t_{i} - t_{i-1}))$ becomes $\beta$, I think from the definition of the Poisson because it's the num of particles born as  $\triangle t \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Maybe Matthew H can comment on or correct my understanding since it was his nice derivation. Thanks again to Matthew.